# Chrome 71 is not clickable after some time: Crashes when dragging and dropping a link

Tags: google-chrome

Since two days, my Chrome stops working after some hours.

All Chrome windows which are opened, do not react on clicks anymore.

I notice that in the moment it stops working, a small grey box appear which - according to

```
xprop $win_id _NET_WM_PID
```

seems to belong to the chrome process tree.

[image: Small Popup]

My theory is that Chrome tries to open a modal which does not work and does not allow me anymore to click anything in the other parts of Chrome.

How can I debug and fix that?

*edit*

I can reproduce it in some cases. It seems to happen when I drag and drop a link to another place. But sometimes it's reproducible sometimes not.

*edit2*

I enabled crash reporting, but not crash was recorded.

*edit3*

Any help on debugging this is appreciated

*edit4* strace shows this:

```
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[19628:19628:0123/095257.459718:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(227)] Couldn't make context current with X drawable.
[19628:19628:0123/095257.459735:ERROR:in_process_command_buffer.cc(575)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure, failed to make context current
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[19628:19628:0123/095257.472138:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(227)] Couldn't make context current with X drawable.
[19628:19628:0123/095257.472165:ERROR:in_process_command_buffer.cc(575)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure, failed to make context current
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[19628:19628:0123/095257.482577:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(227)] Couldn't make context current with X drawable.
[19628:19628:0123/095257.482601:ERROR:in_process_command_buffer.cc(575)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure, failed to make context current
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[19628:19628:0123/095257.492928:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(227)] Couldn't make context current with X drawable.
[19628:19628:0123/095257.492952:ERROR:in_process_command_buffer.cc(575)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure, failed to make context current
[19628:19628:0123/095257.505832:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(227)] Couldn't make context current with X drawable.
[19628:19628:0123/095257.505868:ERROR:in_process_command_buffer.cc(575)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure, failed to make context current
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[19628:19628:0123/095257.516220:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(227)] Couldn't make context current with X drawable.
[19628:19628:0123/095257.516250:ERROR:in_process_command_buffer.cc(575)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure, failed to make context current
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[19628:19628:0123/095257.526476:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(227)] Couldn't make context current with X drawable.
[19628:19628:0123/095257.526511:ERROR:in_process_command_buffer.cc(575)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure, failed to make context current
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[19628:19628:0123/095257.539176:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(227)] Couldn't make context current with X drawable.
[19628:19628:0123/095257.539208:ERROR:in_process_command_buffer.cc(575)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure, failed to make context current
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x2be6a8d53f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[19628:19628:0123/095257.549643:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(227)] Couldn't make context current with X drawable.
[19628:19628:0123/095257.549666:ERROR:in_process_command_buffer.cc(575)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure, failed to make context current
^C--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
```

Comment: Try debug log for a start: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282?hl=en

Comment: Disable plugins...

Comment: Here are some hints if that could help in any case [link1](https://linux.die.net/man/2/futex) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983765/what-is-the-difference-between-futex-wait-and-futex-wait-private) also a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1489454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like updating the Nvidia graphics driver solved the problem. So far no crashes since then. Will keep testing. Wish me luck.

Comment: what version of the driver did you use?

Comment: @ZombieDev nvidia-driver-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64